# Information sources to design a spiral PCB antenna

Tags: pcb-design, rf, antenna, wireless, pcb-antenna

I am starting a huge experimental project and I want/need to explore the frequency independent antennas. I settled on two very interesting antenna topologies that are possible to design as a PCB (spiral-planar, and helical-conical, pictures bellow). However, I faced a major struggle gathering the information about the design of these antennas. Internet is full of 2.4 GHz  WiFi/BT antenna design templates, guidelines and application notes, you can also easily find PCB patch antenna calculators. But thats basically it, I did not find any textbooks, sites forums or any other reliable information sources about the design of different shape PCB antennas. Of course I know that I will have to do endless amount of CST studio simulations and tests before even doing the PCB, but I am searching for a source that would provide me with at least formulas to calculate distances involving impedance, dielectric type, thickness and other parameters. I have to start somewhere... I scanned the C.Balanis ,,Antenna Theory Analysis and Design" which is widely considered to be some kind of antenna design bible, but there were virtually nothing at all (considering my mentioned antennas) Any advices or information sources? Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Voting to re-open as books are neither "rarely useful to others" nor "quickly obsolete". | As for search terms, try "planar antennas" instead.  Last I was searching, I found many articles on the topic, including some interesting ultrawideband designs; but that was some years ago now I think, and YMMV as internet searches seem to decay these days.